# How to destroy a mutex if no thread is locked on it?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

Is there any way using `pthread` which allows us to implement a system such that the last thread unlocking a mutex also destroys it?

Here last means that no other thread is locked on the mutex when this thread leaves.

I am trying to ensure that in an environment of multiple threads and processes, only one path of execution can edit a file at a time.

Comment: The mutex should be destroyed by whoever have created it.

Comment: There are these things called variables. They can store numbers, such as the number of threads running...

Comment: Sounds like file locking might be more what you're looking for.